# Python: changing dictionary recursively

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a question about dictionaries in Python.

I have a dictionary like this:

```
D = {'key1' : ['key3'], 'key2' : {}, 'key3' : ['key2']}
```

And my objective is that all the values are substituted as far as possible like this:

```
After first iteration:
D = {'key1' : {'key3' : ['key2']}, 'key2' : {}, 'key3' : {'key2' : {}]}

After second iteration:
D = {'key1' : {'key3' : {'key2' : {}}}, 'key2' : {}, 'key3' : ['key2']}
```

Is it possible to do that?

I thought something like this:

```
for k in D.keys():
    try:
        if D[k] in D.keys:
            D[k] = D[D[k]]
    except:
        pass
```

I know it's not correct and it's not working. I think that maybe I should use a recursive function.
Could you tell me how can I update the values in the dictionary correctly?

Sorry if my explanation is not clear but I hope you get the idea.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are the values in lists?

Comment: The values are the same as stated above. I mean, the value of 'key1' is a list which contains one element 'key3', and 'key3' is actually a dictionary key with a list 'key2' etc. And I want to substitute these. So, the value of 'key1' should become [['key2]] and this becomes [[{}]]. And finally I'd like to only have nested dictionaries (no lists). I know my explanation is confusing, but I was just thinking whether I can substitute the values of the dictionary with the keys if they match or not.

Comment: The final dictionary should contain nested dictionaries preferably as the values.

Comment: What if the lists contain more than one item? Where are you getting this data structure from?

Comment: Should that be `if D[k] in D` instead of `if D[k] in D.keys`?

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Why are the values in lists? Why do you have lists with only one element?

Comment: Also don't *ever* use `except: pass`. That throws away any helpful error messages that python is giving you. In this case, your code doesn't even run, but you don't know that because of using `except: pass` Get rid of it, and fix the resulting error message.

Comment: Why is `D['key3']` left untouched as `['key2']` rather than expanded to `{'key2' : {}}`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you replace the shallowest parts, i.e. those where the value for the key in `d` is already a `dict`, first:

```
def fix_dict(d):
    fixed = False
    while not fixed:
        fixed = True
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, list) and isinstance(d[v[0]], dict):
                fixed = False
                d[k] = {v[0]: d[v[0]]}
```

Note that this is *not* recursive, but will loop until it does a pass in which there is nothing to change, and is not limited to two layers of nesting.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the solution, but I'm not a Python programmer, so there may be a better way to do it:

```
D = {'key1' : ['key3'], 'key2' : {}, 'key3' : ['key2']}

def sub(D, d):
  if isinstance(d, list) and d[0] in D:
    d = {d[0] : sub(D, D[d[0]])}
  return d

for k in D.keys():
  D[k] = sub(D, D[k])

print D
```

output:

```
{'key3': {'key2': {}}, 'key2': {}, 'key1': {'key3': {'key2': {}}}}
```

Comment: `E = D` binds the two variable names to the same object. If you want to alter one without affecting the other, you will need to `deepcopy` (as the values are themselves mutable).

Comment: Good catch.  I think the E was unnecessary anyway